# Multiple css values To Apply at a single time

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I Want to apply multiple values to css property. I need to apply like this as i mentioned below.

```
.class{align-content: flex-start;
align-content: space-around;
}
```

Both of them Css Values i want to apply at a same time. So I Need like this.

Comment: Can you give more information on what you are trying to do? From my point of view this is not possible, becase you cannot have two values for one attribute. The second one will always overwrite the first one.

Comment: https://pmvshyxuay.localtunnel.me/Numbertank-Search.html

Comment: for .users-list{} i want to do that css so i can remove margin from  insider articles and space generate automatically

Comment: I have still no clue why you need to do this on one element. This of course cannot work. Maybe it's best to try  the solution of @Danield and wrap that element.

Comment: yes i have wrap it but which css i want to apply with that i don't need to create space on my own browser creates space automatically.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do that. The second rule will just override the first rule.

What you *can* do is wrap an element in a container and set up different rules to the container element.

One exception to this that I can think of, is the background property - where multiple value are acceptable in CSS3.

Here's a [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds) article about that

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, the answer is no. Not all CSS properties accept multiple values. However few properties do. E.g- `box-shadow`

```
.my-element{
    box-shadow:0 0 10px 0 #000, 1px 1px 10px 0 #666;
}
```

Here, multiple values are separated by comma (,)

`align-content` is not one of those properties. So no!